# sys.getsizeof(1) and sys.getsizeof(10000) return the same output. Why?

Tags: python, memory

Observe the following (in Python verson 2.7.3):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
24

>>> sys.getsizeof(10000)
24
```

Why does the larger integer only take the same amount of memory (memory of the heap as afaik) of the smaller integer?

Compare this the following

```
>>> sys.getsizeof("1")
38 

>>> sys.getsizeof("100000")
42
```

Comment: Because they're both integer objects

Comment: Why should it take a different amount (I'm not saying it shouldn't, but it would clarify the question to know your reasoning)? Hint: look at `type(1)` and `type(1000)`.

Comment: Please explain first why you would expect a different result, that helps us pinpoint your misunderstanding.

Comment: Try `sys.getsizeof(10000000000000000000000)` and `sys.getsizeof(10**100)`

Comment: If you do `sys.getsizeof("1")` vs `sys.getsizeof("100000")` the larger string takes up more memory. So why would it be different for integers?

Comment: Why the downvote? Why do you think this is a stupid question?

Comment: It's harsh, but I imagine people are downvoting for you not understanding fundamental concepts of how computers store numbers vs. how computers store strings (especially given that you have nearly a 2000 rep rating). I'm glad someone took the time to actually answer you though.

Comment: @aruisdante If that's their reasons, they are wrong and don't understand what downvotes are for (read the mouse over!). Luckily, many people are better than this: They upvote basic but clear, well-written questions (in other words, good questions that happen to be basic), but are harsher if the question is basic but not terribly well-written (but not *terrible* either).

Comment: @delnan *shrugs* I didn't downvote, so I was just speculating.

Comment: @aruisdante I just wanted to give my alternative interpretation because it's less discouraging :-)

Comment: @aruisdante: Thanks for your insight. Rep/experience is misleading imo. You could work for years on only very small scale applications  where having this knowledge of memory usage is much less important than other things not considered fundamental in cs.

Comment: @delnan: thanks for your explanation as well. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings and integers are indeed comparable in that they can be considered as an arbitrarily long sequence of "digits" or "characters". And when you use large enough integers (like 2^70, 5e100, ...) you *will* see memory usage go up<sup>1</sup>. When you add one "character"/"digit" to either, memory usage goes up. For strings, a "character" is roughly what you expect (it gets more complicated with unicode, but whatever).

For integers, however, one "digit" is quite large: Several dozen bits (instead of a single decimal digit, let alone a single bit). This is partly because memory is divided into bits and groups of bits (rather then decimal digits), partly you can't allocate individual bits (at most individual bytes, but even that is wasteful), partly because it's more effective to as many bits as the CPU can work on "natively" (4 to 8 byte usually), and partly to simplify the code.

There's the additional complication that Python 2 has two integer types, `int` and `long`. In the context of the above explanation, `int`s are a weird exception in that they allow you to use a larger *single* digit (e.g. 64 bits instead of 30), but only as long as the number fits into that single digit. The general principle still applies.

<sup>1</sup> Though these integers will have the class `long` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 2):

> If you do `sys.getsizeof("1")` vs `sys.getsizeof("100000")` the larger string takes up more memory. So why would it be different for integers?

Because integers are not stored character by character.

In Python, an integer starts as large as is the platform's native word (plus the extra space needed for the interpreter's internal bookkeeping) because arithmetic is way faster - if you use native types, the processor can directly do the arithmetic on them.

When you get outside the native word boundaries (-2**31 - (2**31-1) on 32 bit machines), Python automatically switches to arbitrary precision arithmetic, where operations are "emulated" in software (of course building on the usual primitives provided by the hardware).

This still won't show you a "string-like" increase because the used space increases in larger chunks (again, typically for efficiency reasons).

Also, looking for an 1:1 decimal digits-integer size relation is misleading, since integers are stored in binary, and a decimal digit "takes" ~3.32 binary digits; so, the size "jumps" won't be on "decimal digits" boundaries, but more on powers of two boundaries.